# Read value from select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, portlet

I have a following scenario,

```
<select id="dropDown" onChange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].onclick();>
<c:forEach items="" var="...">
<c:choose>
<c:when test="">
<option id="<portlet:namespace />..." value="red" onclick="<portlet:namespace />SomeFunction(this.id, 'Contants.SOME_ID', '<c:out value="${some_value}"/>)">red</option>
</c:when>
<c:when test="">
<option id="<portlet:namespace />..." value="yellow" onclick="">yellow</option>
</c:when>
<c:when test="">
<option id="<portlet:namespace />..." value="blue" onclick="">blue</option>
</c:when>
</c:choose>
</c:forEach>
</select>
```

When I select the value say yellow there is no alert at all, only when the page loads first time or if I refresh the page by F5 then I see an alert saying "red". I am not able to alert the selected value.

```
var selected_item = $('#dropDown').val();
alert(selected_item);
```

Is there anything I am missing?

**EDIT**

I have added the sample function for onClick, this is why I use the onClick in the option field. So for each of those  I would call different functions. Is there anyway to get the value of the selected option.

```
<portlet:namespace />SomeFunction(id, some_id, some_value) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `onclick` in the option is doing nothing. Since you are using jQuery, you could not use inline javascript at all.

Remove `onChange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].onclick();` and all `onclick=""`, then try

```
$(function() {
  $('#dropDown').change(function() {
     alert($(this).val());
  });
});
```

Comment: I am using onclick for a reason because I call different function for each clicked one. Please see the edit I made

Answer (score 0):

As you're using jQuery, so you don't need `onclick` to each `option` and `onChange` to `select.`Remove them and try with **[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on)** using `change` event.

```
$('#dropDown').on('change', function() {
   var selected_item = this.value;
   alert( selected_item );
});
```

If you try to update the value of `selected_item` variable at page load then you can trigger the change event like following:

```
$('#dropDown').on('change', function() {
   var selected_item = this.value;
   alert( selected_item );
}).change(); // trigger the change event at page load
```

Comment: I need to keep onclick because I call different functions for each of those <c:when> case. Please see the edit

Comment: @user525146 then try with `click` but remove the `onchage`

Comment: If I remove the onChange the onClick doesn't work for IE6, IE7 and Chrome.